# Is there a way to see what's in MongoDB's cache, and what's not?

Tags: mongodb

I ran into an issue recently where the read ops per second from the disk shot up ~1000x (in frequent spikes) and reached our provisioned IOPS limit in AWS slowing everything down.

My initial thought was that there was something writing data heavily into MongoDB, evicting data that's expected to be in the cache back into disk.

Is there any way to definitively know what's in the cache, as opposed to turning on and off various features that could be causing this issue?

Phrasing it in a way that's more specific to my problem - what's the best way for me to find out why a piece of data that should be in memory is all of a sudden not.

EDIT:
Details of my setup - it's a replica set with mongodb 3.0.6 with WiredTiger as the storage engine.

Comment: It might help if you tell us the version of MongoDB you're running.

Comment: Added it now, thanks for mentioning

Comment: If your memory utilization dances around 85% or more, you can be sure that the working set isn't complete any more.

Comment: Yes, but the interesting thing is that something causes very recent documents to get flushed out of memory. Even if the entire working set is not, we have written some queries based on the assumption that those documents would very likely be in memory.

Comment: Is this a capped collection?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ no we don't use capped collections. And our collections don't have a TTL either.

Comment: The first thing I would do is check the mongoD log for slow queries. Often behavior like this is due to an unindexed query scanning a much larger index/document set than expected. A good way to view this is via the mtools suite's mplotqueries tool, running with the --type nscanned/n argument. Clicking on the dots will print the actual query to your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze using these interesting `ootb` tools:

1. **`mongotop`** `optional_secs` : This command shows in which collection mongo process is spending its time. It also shows time spent in reads and writes.

   - Key points : 
     Unusually High **Read** time generally means **Not using an index**. 
     Unusually High **Write** time might be due the need to maintain an index while insertions.

---

2. **`mongostat`** : (like `iostat`) Tells us IO stats of mongo DB.

   - Key points : **`idx_miss %`** - If a program is using an index, miss rate of index(memory) means program has to go search in disk.